# R: write function to set title of ggplot based on input

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am trying to create a function that will enable me to plot a series of data frames. I am trying to set the title of my plot to a variable that will change based on a variable indicating risk factor.

This is the set-up of a data frame for smoking and a data frame for second hand smoke exposure from riskf (original data frame)

```
smoking <- df.maker(subsetF$Smoking, subsetM$Smoking)
second_smoking <- df.maker(subsetF$Second.hand.smoke.exposure,      
subsetM$Second.hand.smoke.exposure


plot_function <- function(risks, riskf){

plot <- ggplot(risks, aes(provinces, value )) +  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), 
position = "dodge", stat="identity") + scale_fill_discrete(name="Gender") + 
xlab("Provinces and Territories") + ylab("Percentage(%)") + ggtitle("") + 
theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank()) + theme(plot.title     
= element_text(size=20), axis.title.x = element_text(size=14), 
axis.title.y = element_text(size=14)) + geom_hline(yintercept=mean(risks[, 3]))

return(plot)
}


plot_function(smoking)
```

When I plug in smoking for risks, I want my title to be "Smoking by Province in Canada 2014", and if I plug in second_smoking for risks, I want the title to be "Second Hand Smoke by Province in Canada 2014", etc...

Comment: Can't you just add another parameter to use for the title? How is R supposed to know to change "second_smoking" into "Second Hand Smoke"? Is there somewhere you plan to define these translations?

Answer (score 1):

Add in a vector with keys:

```
plot_function <- function(risks){

  riskf  <- gsub("()","",sys.call()[2])
  titles <- c(smoking="Smoking by Province in Canada 2014",
              second_smoking="Second Hand Smoke by Province in Canada 2014")

  plot <- ggplot(risks, aes(provinces, value )) +  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), 
  position = "dodge", stat="identity") + scale_fill_discrete(name="Gender") + 
  xlab("Provinces and Territories") + ylab("Percentage(%)") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20), axis.title.x = element_text(size=14), 
  axis.title.y = element_text(size=14)) + geom_hline(yintercept=mean(risks[, 3]))+
  ggtitle(titles[riskf])

  return(plot)
}
```

And because I don't have your data, here is what the parts that I added do:

```
plot_function <- function(x) {
  riskf  <- gsub("()","",sys.call()[2])
  titles <- c(smoking="Smoking by Province in Canada 2014",
              second_smoking="Second Hand Smoke by Province in Canada 2014")

  print(titles[riskf])
}

smoking <- 1:3

plot_function(smoking)
#                              smoking 
# "Smoking by Province in Canada 2014"
```